# How do I write a unit test to cover the case where an IOException is thrown?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have the following class:

```
    public class FileLoader {   

         private Map<Brand, String> termsOfUseText = new HashMap<Brand, String>();

         public void load() {
            for (Brand brand : Brand.values()) {
                readAndStoreTermsOfUseForBrand(brand);
            }
         }

         private void readAndStoreTermsOfUseForBrand(Brand brand) {
            String resourceName = "termsOfUse/" + brand.name().toLowerCase() + ".txt";          
            InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName);            
            try {
                String content = IOUtils.toString(in);          
                termsOfUseText.put(brand, content);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Failed to find terms of use source file %s", resourceName),e);
            }
         }

        public String getTextForBrand(Brand brand) {
            return termsOfUseText.get(brand);
        }
    }
```

Brand is an enum, and I need all the valid .txt files to be on the classpath. How do I make the IOException occur, given that the Brand enum contains all the valid brands and therfore all the .txt files for them exist?

Suggestions around refactoring the current code are welcome if it makes it more testable!

Comment: +1 - I would override the enum and create a mock enum which includes invalid file name .Also suggest showing your Brand enum and how is load funcation called and where is Brand passed in.

Comment: Enums are final. Overriding isn't an option.

Answer (score 3):

Three options I see right off:

1. Use [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) to mock IOUtils.toString(). I consider PowerMock to be quite a last resort. I'd rather refactor the source to something a little more test-friendly.
2. Extract the IOUtils call to a protected method. Create a test-specific subclass of your class that overrides this method and throws the IOException.
3. Extract the InputStream creation to a protected method. Create a test-specific subclass to override the method and return a mock InputStream.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a bit of refactoring. All your methods are *void*, this usually means they are not functional.
For example, you can extract this functionality:

```
private String readTermsOfUseForBrand(InputStream termsOfUserIs) {
    try {
        String content = IOUtils.toString(in);
        return content;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Failed to find terms of use source file %s", resourceName), e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

So that we can assert on the String result in our tests.
Of course this is not functional code, as it reads from an Input Stream. And it does so with `IOUtils.toString()` method that cannot be mocked easily (well, there's PowerMock but as Ryan Stewart said it's the last resort).

To test IO exceptions you can create a failing input stream (tested with JDK7):

```
public class FailingInputStream extends InputStream {
    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        throw new IOException("Test generated exception");
    }
}
```

And test like that:

```
@Test
public void testReadTermsOfUseForBrand() {
    FileLoader instance = new FileLoader();
    String result = instance.readTermsOfUseForBrand(new FailingInputStream());
    assertNull(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing file will cause `NullPointerException` because `getResourceAsStream` will return `null` and you will have `in==null`. IOException in this case may actually be pretty rare. If it's critical for you to see it, I can only think of instrumenting this code to throw it if code is executed in test scope. But is it really that important?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a mock to accomplish this.

Example (untested, just to give you some thought):

```
@Test(expected=IllegalStateException.class)
public void testThrowIOException() {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(IOUtils.class);
    PowerMockito.when(IOUtils.toString()).thenThrow(
             new IOException("fake IOException"));
    FileLoader fileLoader = new FileLoader();
    Whitebox.invokeMethod(fileLoader, 
            "readAndStoreTermsOfUseForBrand", new Brand(...));
    // If IllegalStateException is not thrown then this test case fails (see "expected" above)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Code below is completely untested
To cause the IOException use:

```
FileInputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName);
in.mark(0);  
//read some data
in.reset(); //IOException
```

To test the IOException case use:

```
void test  
{  
    boolean success = false;  
    try  
    {  
      //code to force ioException  
    }  
    catch(IOException ioex)  
    {  
       success = true;  
    }  
    assertTrue(success);  
}
```

In JUnit4

```
@Test(expected=IOException.class)  
void test  
{  
   //code to force ioException  
}
```

Other JUnit

```
void test  
{  
   try  
   {  
     //code to force IOException  
     fail("If this gets hit IO did not occur, fail test");  
   }
   catch(IOException ioex)  
   {
    //success!
    }  
}
```

Comment: How does that not address the question?  It clearly shows how you can write code that would have a unit test pass when an exception is expected.

Comment: The question is about how to cause the IOException to be thrown in the test, not how to handle an IOException in a test.

Comment: @Woot: I think you're missing the point. The question isn't how to make an InputStream throw an IOException. There are plenty of ways to do that. The question is, given the code as posted, and without changing the way it operates, how can you test the code in the catch block? In other words, OP would like to write a test that calls FileLoader.load(), simulates an IOException, and expects IllegalStateException to be thrown.