# How to code coverage a IOException catch JUnit5

Tags: java, junit, mockito, junit5

Have not been able to write a test that covers the catch in here:

```
public class ServiceToTest {
    public void unzip(byte[] zipFile) {
        try (ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zipFile))) {
            ZipEntry entry;
            while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int len;
                try (var file = new ByteArrayOutputStream(buffer.length)) {
                    while ((len = zipInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                        file.write(buffer, 0, len);
                    }
                    System.out.println(entry.getName());
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            // some logic or rethrow the exception
        } 
    }
}
```

Have tried for a while with the help of Mockito but nothing seems to work with this one, I was thinking on mocking the `ZipInputStream` and throw a `IOException` when it tries to `getNextEntry()` or somehow throw the `IOException` at any moment so I can coverage that catch, but since everything is inside the method I do not know how could I mock something inside it? Another option was to change the `IOException` to `Exception`, and I can cause that catch by passing a null zipFile in my test, but that does not seem like the right way, any ideas?

Also the method does more stuff but I let it here as simple as I could so that we can focus on covering the catch

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I write a unit test to cover the case where an IOException is thrown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701477/how-do-i-write-a-unit-test-to-cover-the-case-where-an-ioexception-is-thrown)

Comment: @HariHaravelan Can not really follow any of the answers they gave, most suggest using powermockito or refactoring the code, but can not see how could I refactor this to make the IOException happen, maybe creating another class, and then inside it, a method that creates the new ZipInputStream, mocking this class and telling it to throw the IOException when creating the new ZipInputStream? But this would be kind of too much for covering that catch, there must be another way because right now the code looks pretty simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with extracting the part which could cause `IOException` and override that in a test implementation to invoke the Exception block code

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class ServiceToTest {
    public void unzip(byte[] zipFile) {
        try (ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(zipFile))) {
            writeToFile(zipInputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
    }

    protected void writeToFile(ZipInputStream zipInputStream) throws IOException {
        ZipEntry entry;
        while ((entry = zipInputStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            try (ByteArrayOutputStream file = new ByteArrayOutputStream(buffer.length)) {
                while ((len = zipInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    file.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                System.out.println(entry.getName());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The test should something be like

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;


class ServiceTest {

    @Test
    public void shouldUnzip() {
        ServiceToTest serviceToTest = new ServiceToTest();
        serviceToTest.unzip(new File("yourFilePath").toString().getBytes());

        //Assert happy path
    }


    @Test
    public void shouldThrowIOException() {
        ServiceToTest serviceToTest = new ServiceToTestChild();
        serviceToTest.unzip(new File("yourFilePath").toString().getBytes());

        //Assert exception path
    }

    private class ServiceToTestChild extends ServiceToTest {
        @Override
        protected void writeToFile(ZipInputStream zipInputStream) throws IOException {
            throw new IOException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, it is accomplishing the objective which is coverage that catch, my only question for now is if it possible to accomplish it without creating the writeToFile method (without the extraction)?

Comment: @BugsOverflow if we don't extract any part of the code inside try block, and override in the child class, we would not be able to simulate the exception

Comment: I can't think of another way to handle this

Comment: Fair, I think it is still a nice way to add, because this is not present in other questions, thanks